# How to handle the gibberish in .log file with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have cloned someone's code from github and tried to run it, but met a unicode problem in python 2.7.

With this piece of code:

```
def indexFile(pt, res_pt):
    print 'index file: ', pt
    wf = open(res_pt, 'w')
    for l in open(pt):
        ws = l.strip().split()
        for w in ws:
            if not w2id.has_key(w):
                w2id[w] = [len(w2id), 1]
            else:
                w2id[w][1] += 1

        wids = [w2id[w][0] for w in ws]        
        print >>wf, ' '.join(map(str, wids))

    print 'write file: ', res_pt
```

The word in the data files are all split and transfer to int id. But the resulting file contains following lines:

[image]

But when I copy it to sublime txt, it changes to:

[image]

All of the strange character gone.

When I copy it to SO editor, it is like:

[image]

The original file is extracted from the `.log` file and it may be the reason of the strange character unseen all the time. So could you please tell me how to handle these strange characters? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have figure out what happened. My program extracts all the files under a folder and analysis them. But a hidden file, `.DS_Store` is in the folder too. So the binary code are extracted too. Solution is to filter that file.